# When ever I try to download something (ex.Discord) I get an error

Tags: software-installation

When ever I try to download something (ex.Discord) I get an error,

> ```
> dpkg was interrupted you must manually run dpkg --configure -a
> ```

What does this mean I not used to Ubuntu and do not know what this means

Comment: Please retry problematic action again and post full error output to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1309597/edit).

Comment: what do you mean by that

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f` and post its output